Pause a page's processes in Angular
So I'm building this website in Angular and Node.js. I'm using routing in my website, and in one of my pages I'm visualizing Point Cloud Data as I get them from a file (I get new data like every 2 seconds or so) in a 3D Viewer (Three.js PCDLoader). Under that viewer, I made a progress bar (with CSS) that shows the completion of the 3D model that is made by the point cloud data. My question is:
Is it possible to pause a pages processes when I move to another page, and then resume those processes when I return to the page?
Like CSS animations, rendering various 3D models and etc.
I want when I move away from the page that contains the viewer and the progress bar to pause, and then resume when i go back to the page.
I know it might be a stupid question or a confusing one, but any help would be appreciated. If you need more info about my situation, I can give you more.
Thanks in advance.

Perhaps an visibility API is what you're looking for?
